# How to keep the empty tokens in for loop

Tags: batch-file

I need to create a script to read a csv file with the ';' char as field delimiter.
I use a FOR /F loop like this:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-7 delims=;" %%a in (file.csv) do (
    echo Ref: %%~a
    echo Gru: %%~b
    echo Sin: %%~c
    echo St: %%~d
    echo Ma: %%~e
    echo Or: %%~f
    echo Es: %%~g
    echo ----------------------
)
```

And the file has this structure:

```
A123;00;B123;0;0;;0;
A124;00;B124;5;0;20010984;0;
```

Some fields are empty, how can i store into 7 variables the content of each corresponding field?

Comment: Because you cannot have an empty variable, if you have empty fields and you want to have a variable, you'll have to supplement it with some content. As you can clearly see from your results, consecutive delimiters are seen as only one, so you cannot simply use a `for /f` loop with `delims` and expect it to work for you like this. I would advise that you instead use [tag:powershell] to assist you with this task.

Comment: or you can get # of lines via `findstr` and a `FOR /F` loop, and read the file using `SET /P` # number of times, and get the length of the string via redirecting it into a temp file, and do variable substrings with `DELAYEDEXPANSION`, and find out that this is all pointless.

Answer (score 3):

The `for /F` loop collapses multiple adjacent delimiters into a single one. But you can work around that when you put the line string in between `""` and replace every delimiter `;` by `";"`, which leads to a string where each delimited item is enclosed in `""`, even blank ones, so adjacent `;` become separated. Afterwards, the quotation marks can easily be removed by using the `~`-modifier for the `for` meta-variable:

```cmd
rem // Read file and loop through all (non-empty) lines:
for /F skip^=1^ usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("file.csv") do (
    rem // Store current line string:
    set "LINE=%%L"
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem /* Surround whole line string in `""` and replace each `;` by `";"`, leading to
    rem    each item appearing in between `""`; the outer-most pair of quotes is needed
    rem    to tell `for /F` that its set is a literal string: */
    for /F "tokens=1-7 delims=;" %%a in (""!LINE:^;=";"!"") do (
        endlocal
        rem // Use the `~`-modifier to remove the surrounding quotes from each item:
        echo Ref: %%~a
        echo Gru: %%~b
        echo Sin: %%~c
        echo St: %%~d
        echo Ma: %%~e
        echo Or: %%~f
        echo Es: %%~g
        echo ----------------------
    )
)
```

This will fail in case any field in the input data contains `;` on its own (in which case the field must be quoted).

Comment: but what if you replaced `;` with a LF? that should be foolproof.

Comment: Well, @HackingAddict1337, then you still have the same problem; you have to distinguish between delimiters `;` and those appearing in the data (when quoted). Anyway, also with line-breaks you have to work around the fact that `for /F` skips empty lines...

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish the task easy using `PowerShell`:

```
powershell -noprofile -command "& {Import-Csv -Delimiter ';' -Path file.csv}"
```

If you insist upon [batch-file](https://ss64.com/nt/) then there exists a (non-trivial) solution:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "eol=' skip=1 delims=" %%G in (file.csv) do (
  set "_line=%%~G"
  REM add a backslash (or other character) in front of every semicolon
  call set "_line=%%_line:;=\;%%"
  FOR /F "tokens=1-7 delims=;" %%a in ('call echo "%%_line%%"') do (
    call :callecho Ref: "%%~a"
    call :callecho Gru: "%%~b"
    call :callecho Sin: "%%~c"
    call :callecho St: "%%~d"
    call :callecho Ma: "%%~e"
    call :callecho Or: "%%~f"
    call :callecho Es: "%%~g"
    echo ----------------------
  )
)
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:callecho
  set "_item=%~2"
  REM display everything except the last character (=added space)
  set "_item=%_item:~0,-1%"
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(%~1 !_item!
  ENDLOCAL
goto :eof
```

**Result**: `D:\bat\SO\61748659.bat`

> ```
> Ref: A&123
> Gru: 00
> Sin: B123
> St: 0
> Ma: 0
> Or:
> Es: g0
> ----------------------
> Ref: A124
> Gru:
> Sin: B&124
> St: 5
> Ma: 0
> Or: 20010984
> Es: g0
> ----------------------
> ```

Using the following sample file: `type file.csv`

```
Ref;Gru;Sin;St;Ma;Or;Es;
A&123;00;B123;0;0;;g0;
A124;;B&124;5;0;20010984;g0;
```

Comment: Regarding your [[tag:batch-file]] code, what happens if the first field is empty? _I'm certain you'll get my point, without me expanding…_.

Comment: @Compo answer updated. I have forgotten default `eol=;` so with `eol='` the script works even if the 1st column in csv is empty…

Comment: @JosefZ what on earth will happen if one line starts with `;` and another `'`? best is `skip^=1^ delims^=^ eol^=` without quotes, although empty lines will still be skipped